# MySQL CPU usage super high since server crashed

Tags: mysql, mariadb, cpu

I've had a big crash on my server 2 days ago, still don't know why, but after resurrect it the mysql server is consuming a huge amount of cpu and I don't know why:

[image]

The server is Mariadb installed by plesk, the my.cnf is completly empty, there is no config at all, everything default like before the crash.

There are no queries in the processlist, but the mysqld process is getting peaks of 200-300% cpu usage:

[image]

Here is what mysqltuner says:

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.7.10 - Major Hayden 
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Logged in using credentials passed on the command line
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.60-MariaDB
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Log file: /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log(23K)
[OK] Log file /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log exists
[OK] Log file /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log is readable.
[OK] Log file /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log is not empty
[OK] Log file /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log is smaller than 32 Mb
[!!] /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log contains 13 warning(s).
[!!] /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log contains 17 error(s).
[--] 14 start(s) detected in /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
[--] 1) 180826 12:06:05 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 2) 180825 12:35:37 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 3) 180825 12:26:25 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 4) 180825 12:23:35 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 5) 180825 10:09:44 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 6) 180825 10:00:49 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 7) 180825  2:08:32 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 8) 180822  3:19:35 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 9) 170919  3:37:31 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 10) 161219  3:28:50 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 10 shutdown(s) detected in /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
[--] 1) 180826 12:06:03 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 2) 180825 12:35:36 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 3) 180825 12:26:24 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 4) 180825 12:23:33 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 5) 180822  3:19:33 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 6) 170919  3:37:30 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 7) 161219  3:28:49 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 8) 161107 12:00:22 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 9) 161107 10:45:08 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 10) 161104 22:21:22 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +Aria +BLACKHOLE +CSV +FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 1.7G (Tables: 27)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 51.3M (Tables: 379)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] There is no basic password file list!

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 12m 16s (1K q [1.935 qps], 118 conn, TX: 1M, RX: 383K)
[--] Reads / Writes: 88% / 12%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 94.1G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 1.2G
[--] Other process memory: 397.8M
[--] Total buffers: 800.0M global + 2.8M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 0B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 833.4M (0.86% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 1.2G (1.27% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/1K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 7% (12/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.85%  (1/118)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 0.0% (0 cached / 984 selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 619 sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 5
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 4% (87 on disk / 1K total)
[!!] Thread cache is disabled
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 18% (400 open / 2K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 8% (91/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (2K immediate / 2K locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance schema is disabled.
[--] Memory used by P_S: 0B
[--] Sys schema isn't installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 12 thread(s).
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (5.5.60-MariaDB)

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.2% (97M used / 536M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 512.0M/119.0M
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 98.6% (7K cached / 101 reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 85.8% (394 cached / 338 writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[!!] InnoDB File per table is not activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/51.3M
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (7.8125 %): 5.0M * 2/128.0M should be equal 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size not used or defined in your version
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 98.54% (95807 hits/ 97227 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 74.14% (129 hits/ 174 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 45 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/1B

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- RocksDB Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] RocksDB is disabled.

-------- Spider Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Spider is disabled.

-------- Connect Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Connect is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: STATEMENT
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log file
    Control error line(s) into /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log file
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    Set thread_cache_size to 4 as a starting value
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64: http://bi t.ly/1mi7c4C
    This is MyISAM only table_cache scalability problem, InnoDB not affected.
    See more details here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49177
    This bug already fixed in MySQL 5.7.9 and newer MySQL versions.
    Beware that open_files_limit (1024) variable
    should be greater than table_open_cache (400)
    Consider installing Sys schema from https://git hub.com/mysql/mysql-sys
    Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this: http://bi t.ly/2wgkDvS
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
    join_buffer_size (> 128.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    thread_cache_size (start at 4)
    table_open_cache (> 400)
    innodb_file_per_table=ON
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=16M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
```

Could you help me? i'm desperate, thanks!

EDIT:

- I've deleted all databases and reimported the dump, same problem.
- I've upgraded mariadb, same problem.
- I've deleted the /var/lib/mysql folder, reinstalled mariadb and imported the dump again, same problem.

Any idea? the only thing I can do is format and reinstall the whole server but I would like to know how repair this kind of problems...

Comment: That look like the broken indexes to me. May be the fastest way to repair your databases is to `mysqldump` them and then drop and recreate from dumps.

Comment: I just did it, let's see if it get fixed

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your database files are corrupt. For the sake of performance, and because it is the ordinary working, mysqld doesn't check their integrity, but assumes they are okay. The side effect is that such events can cause *anything* in the database.

Probably some tree-based index was corrupted on a way, that the nodes are pointing to eachother, which results an inifinite loop walking them.

Considering that your database roughly works, dump all of it, delete the database and reinitalize. The required steps:

1. Export the whole thing, the command: `mysqldump -uroot -p --all-databases --skip-lock-tables > wholedump.sql`
2. Stop the mysqld
3. Make a copy from the database directory (on most Linuxes, it is in `/var/lib/mysql`). If something wouldn't work, you will have least something to recover ( ;-) ).
4. Restart the mysqld
5. Import with the command `mysql -uroot < wholedump.sql`

It is the most simple case, it is not impossible that you will find some *new problem* doing these steps, then make a new question.

**Never can be said enough: you need to have a periodical, automatic backup of all your important databases.** Next time a crash will happen and your db won't be recoverable, or only partially recoverable, what will you do?

Comment: Thank you, i'm gonna try that. I've daily backups of my databases. Hope it works! I just tried to repair all tables & databases but nothing changed, let's see.

Comment: Do I need to delete all databases before the import? i did it without delete them and the problem persist.

Comment: @JohnV Then reinitalize the whole thing (remove mysql, delete /var/lib/mysql, install mysql).

Comment: @JohnV Btw, other database engines have much lesser problems. Maybe you could try postgresql.

Comment: I stopped all cronjobs that I had (crons with queries) and CPU usage is 0% now, so it's still a database problem... I'll check which tables are using those crons and try to figure out whats going on... because I dumped all those tables and the problem is still there.

Comment: @JohnV It is a "tip of iceberg" problem now, we can answer questions but can't debug your system. Cron has most likely nothing to do that. If you have still problems, ask new questions.

Comment: @JohnV There is mysql-slow.log or similar, you can set it in the my.cnf. That logs the queries which were too long.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82261/discussion-between-john-v-and-peterh).

Comment: @johnv Please look in chat for requested information.  There are likely some global variables needing attention that will be discovered with your GLOBAL STATUS and GLOBAL VARIABLE information.  All SWAP space was in use, with ~ 96GB of RAM, be liberal with your swap space, 128M might be reasonable to survive the unpredictable.  Please view my profile, Network profile for contact information including my Skype ID and get in touch with me.

Comment: @johnv I AM a FREE support line.  Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here. 
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini 
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME 
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report if readily available - 7 or more days uptime is helpful 
E) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
F) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps,

Comment: 5.5 is antique.  Upgrade.  You have 96GB of RAM?  Yet very little is being used?

Comment: How many cores?